# Suppression of statement in Postgresql logging

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Given the following SQL function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION log_a_notice() RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'This message is coming from log_a_notice()';
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

I get the following lines in my log file:

`2014-09-11 18:01:20 EDT NOTICE: This message is coming from log_a_notice()
2014-09-11 18:01:20 EDT STATEMENT: SELECT * FROM log_a_notice();`

Is it possible to get the `NOTICE` line, but suppress the `STATEMENT` line?  If so, what are the correct values in postgresql.conf?

I'm using:

```
select version();
                                               version                                                
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.3.5 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2, 64-bit
(1 row)
```

And here are what I *believe* are the relevant `postgresql.conf` values:

```
log_destination = 'stderr'
logging_collector = on
client_min_messages = notice
log_min_messages = notice
log_min_error_statement = notice
log_statement = 'none'
```

I thought that setting `log_min_error_statement = error` would work, but then I don't get the `NOTICE` message in the file.

Comment: What's your current setting for `log_statement`?

Comment: @CraigRinger   I've edited my question to include the requested parameter.

Comment: You have an option to log your stuff in CSV format.  In that case, these two appear in one row (the format is more verbose, though).

Comment: That could be an option. I believe there is an option to log to both, but you can't control the levels for each individually.  Correct?  In other words, log everything info or higher to CSV, but only log warnings or higher to your text file?